# Cannot call React component recursively

Tags: javascript, reactjs

***Update:*** After posting the original question, I figured out that there was a dependency issue with my RequireJS project that was causing the problem. The issue is not related to React.

*You **can** nest/recursively call components the way that I was asking. See this [Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/patik/pen/oBbYbp?editors=0010) as a proof of concept.*

---

I'm trying to make a generic component that takes an object and renders another component based on the object's `type`. Any component would be able to call this generic component to have it render the object appropriately.

```
class Elem extends React.Component {
    constructor () { super(); }

    render () {
        if (this.props.item.type === 'row') {
            return <Row item={this.props.item} />;
        }
        else if (this.props.item.type === 'col') {
            return <Col item={this.props.item} />;
        }
        else if (this.props.item.type === 'btn') {
            return <Button item={this.props.item} />;
        }
        // else if.... for an arbitrary number of types
    }
}
```

In this case it can generate rows and columns for a grid, among other things. Each type has its own HTML structure and set of classes based on the project's needs.

The problem is that grid columns (for example) may contain nested rows, or buttons, or anything else that `<Elem/>` knows how to render. Ideally, I would avoid repeating myself by defining `<Col/>` like this:

```
class Col extends React.Component {
    constructor () { super(); }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="column">
                {this.props.item.contents.map(item => {
                    // Item could be a row, button, or something else, so let <Elem> figure it out:
                    return <Elem item={item} />;
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

and I would pass all of my objects to `<Elem/>` throughout the project. So `<Button/>`, for example, might be rendered multiple places but I've only defined it once.

Unfortunately that throws an error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Col is not defined` at `Elem.render`. I'm guessing it's because I'm nesting components by calling a parent from within the child that it called.

[Codepen demo](http://codepen.io/patik/pen/oBbYbp?editors=0010)—uncomment line 23 to see the error.

**How can I make a generic component like `<Elem/>` that I can call from anywhere** in the app, even it's already part of the chain? Alternatively, how can I render buttons/tables/other components both inside a grid and outside of it, without having to define those components in two places?

For what it's worth, this is for a web app and I'm not using Flux/Redux/etc.

Comment: It sounds like `Link` might be interesting for you

Comment: No offense, but if I change `Col` to `Column` it works inside your codepen, the class is also named `Column`

Comment: protip: React is still just JavaScript and React component "tags" in JSX are still just plain JavaScript objects, so you can do this: `let Type = undefined; switch(this.props.item.type) { case(...) Type = Row; break; case....; } return <Type item={this.props.item} />` - makes the code far easier to maintain, and lets you debug errors with what is in `Type` easier than with the code you've listed.

Comment: @Icepickle you're right. It seems I made a typo in the Codepen and I must have some other problem in my project that made me think the same issue was at play. Looks like I does work how I wanted it to.

Comment: @craigpatik Does the main app have a similar error then, and this MCVE example was wrong?

Comment: @Icepickle it ended up being a dependency issue with RequireJS. When I listed `<Elem>` as a dependency of `<Col>` (while the reverse was already true), `<Elem>` was undefined because of how the dependency tree is build. I solved it for now by defining `<Col>` in the same file. Not a great solution, but I can probably add another layer to fix the dependency issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "[higher-order component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html)".